# How to draw "flag format" lambda derivation diagrams as used in the book Type Theory and Formal Proof: An Introduction

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, logic, proof-package

I'd like to draw "flag format" diagrams for lambda derivation as used in the book "Type Theory and Formal Proof: An Introduction". Below is an example in Chapter 2 of the book. How can I do it? Thanks.

[image: Flag format]

Comment: Welcome! Look at the LaTeX for Logicians website. https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/ : see final comment, 'The flagderiv package can be used to set the variant kind of “flag” proofs some computer scientists like.' If you need further help, please add a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want.

Comment: The website I linked is really good for this stuff. If it isn't there, the chances are it isn't available or it isn't logical ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for all things logical, check the [LaTeX for Logicians](https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/) site, find [the thing you need](https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/) and look up the documentation.

Since you've not given any code, I copied an example from [page 3 of `flagderiv`'s documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/flagderiv/flagderiv.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,flagderiv}


\begin{document}

\begin{flagderiv}
  \introduce{in-x}{x: \mathbb{N}}{Introduction of $x$}
  \assume{as-x}{x > 5}{Assumption}
  \step{big-x}{x > 1}{Arithmetic on \ref{in-x} and \ref{as-x}}
  \conclude{conc}{x > 5 \implies x > 1}{$\implies$-intro on \ref{as-x} and \ref{big-x}}
  \conclude{}{\forall x \in \mathbb{N}: x > 5 \implies x > 1}{$\forall$-intro on \ref{in-x} and \ref{conc}}
\end{flagderiv}

\end{document}
```

[image: flagged derivation]